# Statement about subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional vector space, $U_i\subset V$ subspaces of $V$ for $1\leqslant i\leqslant r$ such that
$$U_1\subset U_2\subset \cdots\subset U_r.$$
If $r>n+1$, then there exists $i<r$ such that $U_i=U_{i+1}$.

I am asked to prove this or give a counterexample, but I don't even understand what is said. Could someone help?

Comment: Which part do you not understand?

Comment: The part after "If..". Actually, the whole thing haha

Comment: Suppose to have $n$ numbers $a_i$ and not subspaces and $1\le i \le r$ and
$$a_1\le a_2 \le\ldots a_r$$
If $r>n+1$ how can all $a_i$ be all distinct?

Comment: A proof by contradiction is pretty straight forward for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that we have $U_1\ne  U_2 \ne \cdots\ne  U_r.$. Then we get

$\dim U_1 < \dim U_2 <... < \dim U_r$ and therefore $\dim U_j \ge j-1$ for $j=1,...,r$.

Result: $n \ge \dim U_r \ge r-1 >n$, a contradiction !

Comment: Why do we have $\dim U_j \geqslant j-1$ for $1\leqslant j\leqslant r$?

Comment: $ \dim U_1 \ge 0$, $ \dim U_2 > \dim U_1$, hence $\dim U_2 \ge 1$, etc ...

Comment: The "if" is used in the last "$>$".

Comment: I finally understand! Thanks so much :)